# Android cannot upgrade CMake version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake

I need to use CMake version at least 3.15 in my Android Studio project.
The installed version was lower so I went to the package manager and installed version 3.18.1 and synced the project (following https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#vanilla_cmake).

But after syncing I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 3.18.1-g262b901
at com.android.repository.Revision.parseRevision(Revision.java:133)
at com.android.repository.Revision.parseRevision(Revision.java:155)
at com.android.build.gradle.external.cmake.CmakeUtils.getVersion(CmakeUtils.java:56)
at com.android.build.gradle.external.cmake.server.ServerFactory.create(ServerFactory.java:42)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.CmakeServerExternalNativeJsonGenerator.executeProcessAndGetOutput
```

I tried reopening Android Studio, upgrading my NDK version to 22.1 but I get the same error. I am using lattest Android Studio version 4.2.1.

What prevents a specific CMake version from being used ? Gradle version ? NDK version ? Android Studio version ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it finally by displaying more logs on the error message.
The key action is to update Gradle in my project level build.gradle file,

I changed:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
```

To:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

**first** go to your pc dir wich android sdk is installed

```
in my pc dir is ->  C:\Users\lotka-pc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake
```

and delete the older version

**second** in your gradle file **module** you should change the version of cmake

```
    externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        version '3.18.1'
    }
}
```

**third** - you should check dir

```
src/main/cpp/CmakeList.txt
```

and check the version

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
```

these will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (yet not related to the NDK so I gave your solution a shot). I just want to preface that your answer helped me realize something that was horribly wrong with my installation of Android Studio in terms of configuration.

Uninstalling and Reinstalling the IDE helped me find the true culprit as to why Android Studio just wouldn't compile: Inadequate [SFML configuration for Android](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Building-SFML-for-Android) in my case. I don't have enough reputation points as this is a new account, or I'd upvote your answer for helping me realize what I did wrong.

Thank you!